# Fourier Transform of $f'(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)$ is $F(k)$, find the Fourier transform of function $f'(x) = [f(-x)]^*$

I am unsure if $f'(x)$ in this case is the derivative function of $f(x)$ or just an entire other function.

If $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ how do I approach this question?

Comment: The way you written $f'(x)$ suggests that it's not the derivative of $f$.

Comment: Could it be that, with your notation, $f'(x) = \overline{f(-x)}$ (the bar is the conjugate) ?

Comment: @C.Dubussy Yes, I believe the right hand side of the equation is so. Just unsure of whether or not the left hand side refers to the derivative of $f$

Comment: If you know the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, you can easily find the Fourier transform of $f(-x)$ and $\overline{f(-x)}$, and integrating by parts you can find the Fourier transform of $f'(x)$. So just do it !

Comment: @Limzy $f'$ has nothing to do with derivative here. It is just another function which is actually the same as $f$, but reversed and conjugated. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{F(k)\}=f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(k)e^{ikx}dk\tag{1}$$

Assume $\mathcal{F}\{(f(-x))^*\}=G(k)$. Thus

$$(f(-x))^*=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G(k)e^{ikx}dk$$
$$f(-x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G^*(k)e^{-ikx}dk$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G^*(k)e^{ikx}dk\tag{2}$$

Comparing $(2)$ with $(1)$ we have

$$G(k)=\mathcal{F}\{(f(-x))^*\}=F^*(k)$$